# prevent users from leaving the current screen until a timer has expired?

Tags: react-native

In React Native, how can we prevent users from leaving our screen when they press the home or recent apps button until a timer has expired?
.when user press home key after 3 second the home screen of my applilcation automatically re open.

Comment: You want to prevent the user from going to the home screen or switching apps?

Comment: i want the user did not leave form applciation unitill he pressed exit button which i provided in application.when he press home key than our application went to backgorund .so i prevent this ?

Comment: I don't think it's possible - at least I hope not, imagine having an app you couldn't exit.

Comment: the application is just like parent control app .when parent opened my application they select some specific applicatio ,photos,videos to used to childeren. so if the user press home key they can exit the application .to prevent this i want to lock screen for specific time ,when time is up it autonatically navigate to password screen if he enter correct password than he exit from my application.

Comment: i have found the solution of this problem finallay.

Comment: for this purpose we could replace home screen and set our application as home screen.so in this method when user click on home key it will open  our application .

Comment: "How can I hijack the user's phone with my app?"  Why would you think this is something you're allowed to do?